# spring boot + gcloud + "502 Bad Gateway"

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm trying to deploy on gcloud this project:
https://github.com/ITger/PolishAPI_sample
locally works fine, but on gcloud  I'm always receiving the 502 error.

mvn clean package appengine:deploy command run without problems.

**In logs (gcloud app logs tail) there are no errors only Info and Debug messages.**
For a week I have been looking for a solution and trying many suggestions found in internet,I followed google, dzone, etc tutorials, with no luck.

I appreciate any help

EDITED (resp to  John Hanley):
ad 1: my code is more than 165 java files, so how to show it???

ad 2: app.yaml:

```
runtime: java
env: flex
instance_class: F2
runtime_config:
  jdk: openjdk8
#env_variables:
#  SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: "gcp"
handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: this field is required, but ignored
readiness_check:
  check_interval_sec: 15
  timeout_sec: 14
  failure_threshold: 2
  success_threshold: 2
  app_start_timeout_sec: 1200
```

ad 3: As I said there are **NO ERRORS** in logs only spring info and debug messages.

application.properties file:

```
debug=true
spring.application.name=polish-api-psd2
springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.path=/api-docs
server.port=${port:8080}
spring.jackson.date-format=pl.itger.PolishAPI.RFC3339DateFormat
#Mongo Config
spring.data.mongodb.database=PolishAPI
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://polishapi-user:SECRET CLUSTER DATA
spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation=true
log4j.category.org.springframework.data.mongodb=DEBUG
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %40.40c:%4L - %m%n
logging.level.pl.itger=DEBUG
logging.level.root=WARN
```

App engine Firewall rules:

```
Priority 
1000
Action on match
Allow
IP range 
0.0.0.0/0
```

When I run the "`**mvn clean spring-boot:run -P cloud-gcp**`" in the Google Cloud Shell console the app starts fine, in the Web Preview the app starts well with the predefined swagger ui page:

```
https://8080-dot-10127310-dot-devshell.appspot.com/
```

with all models and api's displayed.
When I invoke in the browser  "`https://8080-dot-10127310-dot-devshell.appspot.com/api-docs`" also works well. Calling with curl any rest service on that url results in"Access Forbidden".

**But**, after `mvn -DskipTests package appengine:deploy -P cloud-gcp` nothing works, only `502 Bad Gateway`.

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: Setting traffic split for service [default]...
[INFO] GCLOUD: ..............................................................done.
[INFO] GCLOUD: Deployed service [default] to [https://polish-api-psd2.appspot.com]
[INFO] GCLOUD:
[INFO] GCLOUD: You can stream logs from the command line by running:
[INFO] GCLOUD:   $ gcloud app logs tail -s default
[INFO] GCLOUD:
[INFO] GCLOUD: To view your application in the web browser run:
[INFO] GCLOUD:   $ gcloud app browse
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  09:15 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-12-12T15:49:39+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
p_zerynger@cloudshell:~/PolishAPI_sample/server (polish-api-psd2)$
```

full Log (its very short, different from that after "mvn spring-boot:run -P cloud-gcp" I dont know why):

```
ar!/, jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-jdbc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/aspectjrt-1.9.5.jar!/, jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/lombok-1.18.10.jar!/, jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/core-1.5.3.jar!/, jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/proxytoys-1.0.jar!/, jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/gson-2.8.6.jar!/, jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/annotations-17.0.0.jar!/, jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar!/, jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar!/]
2019-12-12 14:48:53 default[1]
2019-12-12 14:48:53 default[1]    .   ____          _            __ _ _
2019-12-12 14:48:53 default[1]   /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
2019-12-12 14:48:53 default[1]  ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
2019-12-12 14:48:53 default[1]   \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
2019-12-12 14:48:53 default[1]    '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
2019-12-12 14:48:53 default[1]   =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
2019-12-12 14:48:53 default[1]   :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.2.RELEASE)
2019-12-12 14:48:53 default[1]
2019-12-12 14:48:54 default[1]  2019-12-12 14:48:54.093  INFO 1 --- [           main] p.i.P.PolishAPI_2_1_2_SpringBoot         : Starting PolishAPI_2_1_2_SpringBoot v1.0.1 on e1b35acb6032 with PID 1 (/app.jar started by root in /)
2019-12-12 14:48:54 default[1]  2019-12-12 14:48:54.096 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] p.i.P.PolishAPI_2_1_2_SpringBoot         : Running with Spring Boot v2.2.2.RELEASE, Spring v5.2.2.RELEASE
2019-12-12 14:48:54 default[1]  2019-12-12 14:48:54.098  INFO 1 --- [           main] p.i.P.PolishAPI_2_1_2_SpringBoot         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-12-12 14:48:54 default[1]  2019-12-12 14:48:54.102 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Loading source class pl.itger.PolishAPI.PolishAPI_2_1_2_SpringBoot
2019-12-12 14:48:54 default[1]  2019-12-12 14:48:54.341 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Loaded config file 'jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/application.properties' (classpath:/application.properties)
2019-12-12 14:48:54 default[1]  2019-12-12 14:48:54.345 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@6c3708b3
2019-12-12 14:52:42 default[1]  I1212 14:51:56.693214    26 callbacks_monitor.cc:66] Cloud Debugger call "JVMTI:ClassPrepare" completed after 25847 ms
```

+++++++++
in cloud http load balancer log I found this:

```
jsonPayload: {
  @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.loadbalancing.type.LoadBalancerLogEntry"   
  statusDetails: "failed_to_connect_to_backend"   
 }
```

> It's crazy... now timeout:

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] App Engine Flexible timed out while configuring resources, internal operation projects/polish-api-psd2/regions/europe-west1/operations/3343fc51-2991-4da1-ba45-128bd897d92f
```

Comment: 1) Show your code in your question. 2) For App Engine include the app.yaml. 3) Show the exact error messages. 4) Which App Engine are you using? 5) Your problem is probably that your app not listening on the correct port. 6) We won't go to a link, you must include everything required in your question. Links break or become invalid, you may have made a mistake, etc.

Comment: When you move to cloud you need to open some port in order to interact. Have you done that ? By default all ports are blocked.

Comment: What are the URLs tested in local and in AppEngine? (Copy the full URL, HTTPS included but hide your project name) Do you have custom domain on AppEngine?

Comment: Is there a proxy server between your machine and the AppEngine?

Comment: Perhaps I opened the ports in the wrong way - how to do it? I dont have custom domain. There is no proxy server. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Every deployment has a version number assigned to it. 
Verify if that version number appears in the "versions" section under "app engine"
of your GCP project. If the version number does appear, logs will be provided in StackDriver detailing any possible deployment errors that occurred.

If the version number does not appear then re-deploy the project and this time enable the verbosity flag to generate deploy logs.[1]

Lastly, try deploying a bare minimum "Hello World" app and see if that works if the issue is not code-related.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/#--verbosity

Comment: Version Status Traffic Allocation Instances  Runtime Environment Size  Deployed Diagnose Config     
`1   Serving 
100% 
6
java Flexible 0 B 12.12.2019, 8:11:08 PM by p.zerynger@gmail.com`

Comment: Through process of elimination, we now need to determine if the issue is related to your code, configuration or infrastructure. Can you deploy a “Hello World” app using the same app.yaml file from your previous project and see what happens?

Comment: springboot minimum HelloWorld also doesnt work - timeout: .........failed.
[INFO] GCLOUD: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Timed out waiting for the app infrastructure to become healthy.
[INFO] --------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  30:19 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-12-13T19:27:39+01:00
For this test I deleted all projects on gcloud and created a new one. On intellij works well. Money for nothing...

Comment: another try on the same HelloWorld, exactly the same sources: GCLOUD: DONE
[INFO] GCLOUD: --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] GCLOUD:
[INFO] GCLOUD: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: The following quotas were exceeded: IN_USE_ADDRESSES (quota: 8, used: 8 + needed: 1).
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  04:08 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-12-13T20:50:21+01:00

Comment: Can you deploy again the bare minimum"Hello World" app without Spring Boot?

Comment: I appreciate your help thank you. I deployed the demo descibed in [link](https://mydeveloperplanet.com/2019/04/10/deploy-spring-boot-app-to-gcp-app-engine/) . After many many attempts with errors like above (_timeouts_, _exceded cuotas_, _"The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request."_) with no source code changes only redeploying again and again, that demo suddenly **WORKED**. I'm not a java and spring newbie, but gcloud is new to me. I'm totally lost why so many problems with gcloud. Every 10 minutes the spring boot logo **reappears** in gcloud logs

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
resources:
  memory_gb: 4
```

Inside your yaml file.